# Insert predefined text at cursor position

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to insert some text at the cursor's position but I didn't find the required code at the API docs.
Is there any function that I could put the parameters within, which solves my problem? This is just for testing.

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
var fs = require('fs');
var flow = require('xml-flow');
var inFile = fs.createReadStream('./your-xml-file.xml');
var xmlStream = flow(inFile);

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "intrexx-js-lib" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('intrexx-js-lib.start', () => {

        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if(!editor){
            vscode.window.showErrorMessage("Editor does not exist!");
            return;
        }

        if (editor.selection.isEmpty) {
            const position:vscode.Position = editor.selection.active;
            //vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`line: ${position.line} character: ${position.character}`);

        }

    });


    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although [rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65626729/4596058)'s code works, if any text is selected it will overwrite that text. If you want to ensure that no text is deleted by the insert operation, use `edit.insert` instead. For rioV8's second example, that means doing this:

```js
vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('intrexx-js-lib.start', (editor, edit) => {
    editor.selections.forEach((selection, i) => {
        let text = "FooBar " + i;
        edit.insert(selection.active, text);  // insert at current cursor
    })
});
```

Comment: Notice in the edit what I did to get javavscript syntax coloring.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different command register function, it gives you a `TextEditorEdit`:

```js
vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('intrexx-js-lib.start', (editor, edit) => {
    let text = "FooBar";
    edit.replace(editor.selection, text);
});
```

For use with multiple cursors, you'll have to iterate over `editor.selections`:

```js
vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('intrexx-js-lib.start', (editor, edit) => {
    editor.selections.forEach((selection, i) => {
        let text = "FooBar " + i
        edit.replace(selection, text)
    })
});
```

Comment: this shows error: Argument of type 'Selection' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Position'.
  Type 'Selection' is missing the following properties from type 'Position'

Comment: @kushagra-aa `edit.relace` allows `Selection` as first argument, so you are possibly doing something different

Comment: yeah sorry, I was using edit.inset